# vue 2 how to pass index variable in v-bind:class ternary?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i'm trying to use index (inside a v-for) to create dynamic class in vuejs, but seems not working properly, can someone suggest me how to do?

```
v-bind:class="['GiallaSoto'+index ? 'minus' : !'GiallaSoto'+index, 'plus']"
```

the 'GiallaSoto' variable is always true. however i declared it as false

```
    data: function(){
    return{
        servizioAggiunto : '',
        'GiallaDesc':false,
        'GiallaTutti':false,
        'GiallaSoto0':false,
        'GiallaSoto1':false,
        'GiallaSoto2':true,
        'GiallaSoto3':false,
    }
}
```

i suppose is something related to a correct sintax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the object syntax, combined with a method to property obtain the correct value from data.

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: function(){
    return{
      servizioAggiunto : '',
      'GiallaDesc':false,
      'GiallaTutti':false,
      'GiallaSoto0':false,
      'GiallaSoto1':false,
      'GiallaSoto2':true,
      'GiallaSoto3':false,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getClass(val, index){
      return {
        minus: !this['GiallaSoto'+index],
        plus: this['GiallaSoto'+index]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.minus{
  background-color: red;
}
.plus{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 4" 
       :class="getClass('GiallaSoto', index - 1)" >
    {{index}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a name a certain ;-)

Comment: @PdsInk Just be aware that if you end up with indexes > 3 this code will end up returning `minus` all the time.